# Sublime Text 2 - Run Plugin on Program Startup

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2

I'm trying to create a plugin to switch the font_face setting based on the current OS.  I have used Dropbox to sync all of my settings and I use a Mac at work and Windows at home.  I believe I have created a plugin that works (although maybe not perfect as this is my first attempt at a plugin and python for that matter!) but my problem comes when I try to make it run when Sublime Text 2 starts up.

I've searched seemingly to the ends of the internet and haven't been able to find a single article on "running a plugin at startup" which makes me either think it's not possible, or it's so easy to do that no one has thought to write about it.

Here is my code:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class OsFontSwitcherCommand(sublime_plugin.ApplicationCommand):
def run(self):
    s = sublime.load_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")

    if sublime.platform() == "osx":
        s.set("font_face", 'Courier')
    else:
        s.set("font_face", 'Consolas')

    sublime.save_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")
```

This works great, but I have to call it manually every time I launch the program for it to work.

I was able to get the plugin to run as soon as it was loaded by doing the following, but it seems to run before the Default and User settings are actually loaded and the result is that it wipes out all my other settings:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

s = sublime.load_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")

if sublime.platform() == "osx":
    s.set("font_face", 'Courier')
else:
    s.set("font_face", 'Consolas')

sublime.save_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")
```

I considered using the set_timeout() method, but that seems really hacky.

I'd like to expand this into a more fleshed out plugin so that you could make full configurations for Windows and OSX and have them always load correctly based on the current OS. Getting it to run on startup automatically is the key.

I also tried making `Preferences (Windows).sublime-settings` and `Preferences (OSX).sublime-settings` in my /Packages/User folder, but they don't seem to get picked up.  Others have noticed this issue too: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5135

Any thoughts on how to get this plugin running on startup would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks very much.

Comment: I know the Sublime Package Control plugin runs at startup so it's definitely possible.  As I haven't actually needed this functionality I cannot give you a direct answer, however, the `Package Control.py` file would most likely contain the answer to your question.  `Preferences -> Browse Packages` then go to the Package Control folder.  Good luck!

Comment: @bdiamante: thanks for the direction.  I checked out `Package Control.py` and at the very bottom there is a set_timeout call waiting for 2 seconds with a comment to the effect of: Start Package Control shortly after Sublime starts so it doesn't cause errors with any key binds, settings, etc.  Thanks for the help.  I'm surprised there is no other way to do this as it doesn't seem like a reliable way to know when the settings have been loaded.  I've added this to my plugin and it works.  Just as long as Sublime starts within 2 seconds :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question and the original poster was asking about Sublime Text 2, but I just solved a similar problem for myself, and Sublime Text 3 offers a convenient way to do this.

If you defined a module-level `plugin_loaded` function, Sublime Text 3 will execute your code whenever your plugin loads.

I wrote up a [blog post about this with more details and some sample code](http://sublimetexttips.com/execute-a-command-every-time-sublime-launches/).

Comment: Thanks Josh, I'll definitely look into upgrading my plugin code for Sublime Text 3, would be really nice to not have to rely on a arbitrary timeout count.

Comment: Hi Josh, I updated my plugin code and it works great now. Thanks for the tip. Here's the final plugin code:

import sublime, sublime_plugin

def plugin_loaded():
s = sublime.load_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")
if sublime.platform() == "osx":
  s.set("font_face", 'Courier')
else:
  s.set("font_face", 'Consolas')
  sublime.save_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")